# Kartik select2 yii2 - Select All and Unselected All is not connected with select, selecting, unselect event

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I have selecting, unselect and unselecting event. But when I click on select all or unselect all none of these events are called.

This is the plugin link
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

Comment: [Selec2 Event List](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events)

Comment: None of event are calling when I click Select All/Unselect all

Answer (score 3):

There is an event that is fired. Its logic is defined in here:

[Select2 Krajee JS Official Source Code](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2/blob/03f202e9e2415f4c84e93a64074d85677fd0cc51/assets/js/select2-krajee.js#L62)

The name of the event for select all is `krajeeselect2:selectall` and for unselect all is `krajeeselect2:unselectall`.

Consuming the event via JQuery is done as always:

```
$('#myKartikSelect2Id').on("krajeeselect2:selectall", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

$('#myKartikSelect2Id').on("krajeeselect2:unselectall", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Hope it helps (:

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful. I was using select2:selectall

Comment: This answer can be partially correct but not entirely. After this krajeeselect2:selectall event the change event is triggering and so this event is not acting the same way like select2:select or select2:unselect event

Comment: @Ish maybe if you could elaborate a little more of why this behaviour is undesired? As I understood you needed an event that fired on `Select All` and `UnSelect All`, and `krajeeselect2:(un)selectall` does specifically that. The source code has no other event that fires on (un)select all scenarios.

Comment: I have a similar problem, what can i do

Comment: @ovicko is your problem the one explained in the question? If so, the answer provided solves it. If not, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find better solution but with this options you can override "Select all" checkbox with empty space.

```
'toggleAllSettings' => [
   'selectLabel' => '',
   'unselectLabel' => '',
   'selectOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success'],
   'unselectOptions' => ['class' => 'text-danger'],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very correct, but using this works `$this->renderAjax()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).